# Why does ui:fragment not work in custom tag file?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, tagfile, conditional-rendering

I created the following custom tag for my JSF 2.2 application:

```
<et:gridRowLabelPasswordMessage
    label_name="Password"
    password_id="password"
    password_value="#{myAuthenticator.password}"
    password_required="true"
    password_match=""
    password_binding="#{pw}" />
```

The following is the key part of the custom tag file:

```
<p:password
    id="#{password_id}"
    value="#{password_value}"
    placeholder="#{label_name}"
    binding="#{password_binding}"
    required="#{password_required}"
    requiredMessage="#{label_name} is required."
    match="#{password_match}" />
```

Due to an issue with PrimeFaces p:password, I can not set match="" so I need to test password_match and only include match if password_match is not empty.   After first, I tried to use the ui:fragment as shown below:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{empty password_match}">
    <p:password
        id="#{password_id}"
        value="#{password_value}"
        placeholder="#{label_name}"
        binding="#{password_binding}"
        required="#{password_required}"
        requiredMessage="#{label_name} is requred." />
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty password_match}">
    <p:password
        id="#{password_id}"
        value="#{password_value}"
        placeholder="#{label_name}"
        binding="#{password_binding}"
        required="#{password_required}"
        requiredMessage="#{label_name} is requred."
        match="#{password_match}" />
</ui:fragment>
```

The result was that when I set password_match = "" the p:password was not rendered at all.   In other words, neither test returned true.  My only theory is that ui:fragment doesn't work in the custom tag files.

I then changed my code to the following and it worked as expected.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{empty password_match}">
        <p:password
            id="#{password_id}"
            value="#{password_value}"
            placeholder="#{label_name}"
            binding="#{password_binding}"
            required="#{password_required}"
            requiredMessage="#{label_name} is required." />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <p:password
            id="#{password_id}"
            value="#{password_value}"
            placeholder="#{label_name}"
            binding="#{password_binding}"
            required="#{password_required}"
            requiredMessage="#{label_name} is required."
            match="#{password_match}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: The match attribute of an password should point to the id of a second `p:password`. Does it? And why do you need the binding? And what PF / JsFimpl version?

Comment: You're creating 2 components with the same id. That could be the issue. `rendered=false` means component gets created, but not rendered. `c:when test="false"` means component does not get created.

Comment: @Vsevolod: It is. Only, I wonder why OP didn't got an exception like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768527/jsf-conditional-includes-cause-component-id-has-already-been-found-in-the-view

Comment: @Kukeltje: I want my tag to be able to handle the case where I set the match and the case where I do not set the match.  I believe that PrimeFaces 5.2.8 has a bug as described in [PrimeFaces Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=42851).  I am using GlassFish 4.1.   I bind the password to a variable so that I can test for invalid and display a message.   See above link for complete code.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov:  Thanks!  I am just beginning to understand the JSF lifecycle and the difference between [taghandlers and components](http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat).   Your answer fits in well with my new understanding.